# Changing a value in Javascript doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript

I've been trying to do a larger project and been coding in small chunks, but I came across trouble with what seems to be something very simple and I'd appreciate a few more eyes looking at this.

I'm trying to change a value of a button in a table. But I can't seem to get it to work. My html aside from the basic headings is . . .

```
<table id = "puzzle">
    <tr>
        <td> <button type = "button" id="b00"> 1 </button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and my js is

```
document.getElementById("b00").innerHTML = "5";
```

Other things I've been doing have been working like printing and such. It should be noted that when I try to set the element equal to a var and print it, it prints null. Is that normal? Thanks for any help.

Comment: When I copy and paste your code in jsfiddle, it works

Comment: Looks to me like your html & js are working fine: http://codepen.io/cam5/pen/gwjkAk Is there maybe something you're leaving out?

Comment: Where did you put your JS code? If it's before your `<table>`, it won't be able to get the element because it doesn't exist yet.

Comment: @DiegoCardoso is right. If you're running your script before the HTML is generated, then you won't change it due to it not being rendered at the time. Good call

Answer (score 4):

I had put the js file in the header and had made the html table in the body of the code. It couldn't find the table because it didn't exist yet. Full Credit to Diego Cardoso and James for helping me out.